# Massive deletes in snowflake fact tables

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In snowflake. Is there any best practice for erasing/purge old data i.e. running over the edge historically for big fact tables? After all, this is what you traditionally use partitions for in a conventional RDBMS as SQL Server. Truncate a partition in SQL Server takes milliseconds.

Best Regards
Jan

Answer (score 1):

You can use clustering on Snowflake in a similar fashion as partitions in SQL Server.  They aren't exactly the same, but if you are deleting old data by date, then you can cluster by that date.  This way when you delete older micropartitions, Snowflake won't need to create new ones or search inside existing ones to find the records to delete...it'll simply delete the files that need to be deleted, which is a metadata operation and is fast.

That said, if you are loading data in order of the same date field, then your table may already be fairly well clustered on that date field.  If the fact is very large, clustering on that date field may take some time if it isn't already naturally ordered that way, but it has a lot of benefits, including the use-case that you've asked about in this post.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes this would be the natural way to do this but I read a post that someone had problems with long running deletes with this scenario. But if this is best practice I guess this fellow had a badly clustered table.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that post?  Most issues I've seen is people thinking that they need to iterate through and delete a small portion of records at a time, which is incorrect.  Otherwise, this is the best approach.  Clustering creates micropartition pruning and will dramatically decrease the delete times.

Comment: https://support.snowflake.net/s/question/0D50Z000090mebVSAQ/how-can-i-delete-a-huge-amount-of-data-from-a-table

Comment: Badly...or differently clustered.  If the cluster key is something other than the date you are deleting by, then the delete statement could rebuild the entire table.  If the warehouse is too small to accomplish that, then it could take a very long time.